# Cypress pagination handling

Tags: javascript, methods, pagination, automated-tests, cypress

I want first to get the #product_list for the full elements list on the current page and then find every element in this list
If the element .ajax_block_product.col-xs-12.col-sm-4.col-md-3[data-id-product='22578'] is in the first page then click it, else click on the #pagination_next_bottom button on the bottom of page and search again in other pages to find the element present in #product_list element

I tried with this function but it only finds every page and navigates without clicking on desired element.

```
// findItem("Printer Brother MFP Laser HL1222WEYJ1");

      // function findItem(value) {
      //   let found = false;
      //   let attempts = 0;
      //   const maxAttempts = 20; // Define a maximum number of attempts
      
      //   function clickNext() {
      //     cy.get("#pagination_next_bottom").click()
      //     cy.wait(5000);
      //   }
      
      //   function findInPage() {
      //     if (found || attempts >= maxAttempts) {
      //       return; // If item found or max attempts reached, exit
      //     }
      
      //     cy.get("#product_list li div.produkti h5").each(itemNameEl => {
      //       const itemText = itemNameEl.text();
      //       console.log(itemText);
      //       if (itemText === value) {
      //         found = true;
      //         cy.get(itemNameEl).should('be.visible').click(); // Click the parent element of the product
      //         return false;
      //       }
      //     });
      
      //     if (!found) {
      //       clickNext(); // Click the "Next" button
      //       attempts++; // Increment attempts
      //       findInPage(); // Continue searching on the next page
      //     }
      //   }
      
      //   findInPage();
      // }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're feeling a bit frustrated by the recursion, try it with the [cypress-recurse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-recurse) plugin.

The simplest code would be as follows:

```js
const itemsSelector = '#product_list li div.produkti'  // leaving off h5
const nextPageSelector = '#pagination_next_bottom'
const value = 'Printer Brother MFP Laser HL1222WEYJ1'

recurse(
  () => cy.get(itemsSelector),
  (items) => expect(items).to.contain(value),
  {
    post: () => cy.get(nextPageSelector).click()
  }
)
.contains(value)   // filter down to one item
.click()
```

Notes:

- this recurse() returns all items on the page, so filter it with `.contains()`
- it works with `expect(items).to.contain(value)` because your value is quite unique, but if it could partially appear in a different item then you would have to use `.each()`

Answer (score 4):

The recursive code looks pretty good, but keep in mind Cypress commands `get/each` are asynchronous, so you need to wait for them to finish before doing checks like `if (!found)`.

This applies in two places

- the `if (!found)` before `clickNext()`
- the `if (found || attempts >= maxAttempts)` at the top

You don't need to `return`, just check the `found` variable and allow the function to drop through and finish if `found` is set.

Do both of those with a `cy.then()` wrapper.

```js
let found = false;
let attempts = 0;
const maxAttempts = 20;

function clickNext() {
  cy.get("#pagination_next_bottom").click()
  cy.get("#product_list li div.produkti h5", {timeout:5000})
    .should('have.length.gt', 0) 
}

function findInPage() {

  cy.then(() => {         // to exit when found wrap this check 

    if (!found && attempts < maxAttempts) {
      cy.get("#product_list li div.produkti h5").each(itemNameEl => {
        if (itemNameEl.text() === value) {
          found = true;
          cy.get(itemNameEl)
            .parent()                         // NOTE <h5> parent
            .should('be.visible').click(); 
          return false;
        }
      })

      cy.then(() => { // wrap this check to allow get/each to complete
        if (!found) {
          clickNext();
          attempts++; 
          findInPage(); 
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

You can replace the `cy.wait(5000)` with a check for page item count, maybe `cy.get("#product_list li div.produkti h5").should('have.length.gt', 0)`, or check the page number element.

Timeout is always better than `cy.wait()`.

---

Maybe also alias the found element and click it after the search has finished.

In general, you should try to **separate query code from action code**, because actions can change the DOM and invalidate queries that have already run.

```js
function findInPage(value) {
 ...
      if (itemText === value) {
        found = true;
        cy.get(itemNameEl).parent().as('product')
}

findInPage();

cy.get('@product').should('be.visible').click()
```

Answer (score 3):

Two things that *might* be a problem (since click is not happening)

- `itemText === value` This might need an inexact match like `itemText.includes(value)` due to whitespace chars
- `cy.get('itemNameEl')` maybe needs to be `cy.wrap('itemNameEl')`, although I'm not convinced of that

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that the line where you check if the object is found  (`if (!found)`) is synchronous, and runs before Cypress executes (asynchronously) and potentially updates the value of `found`. Because you are executing Cypress commands inside of the synchronous functions, I'd recommend using a Cypress custom command to handle your recursion.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("findItem", (value, attempt) => {
  let currAttempt = attempt ?? 0;
  const maxAttempts = 20;

  if (attempt < maxAttempts) {
    let found = false;
    cy.get("#product_list li div.produkti h5")
      .each(($item) => {
        const itemText = $item.text();
        console.log(itemText);
        if (itemText === value) {
          found = true;
          return false;
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        if (!found) {
          cy.get("#pagination_next_bottom").click();
          cy.wait(5000);
          cy.findItem(value, currAttempt++);
        } else {
          cy.wrap($item).should("be.visible").click(); // Click the parent element of the product
        }
      });
  } else {
    expect(true === false); // placeholder assertion to fail if too many attempts are made
  }
});
```

Also, moving the `cy.wrap($item)...` line to the `.then()` block allows the `.each()` block to be completely synchronous and not be in competition with any Cypress commands for execution times.